# How to get links to user and tag by its name?

Tags: permalinks, tags, author

For example i have the name of user or the name of tag. Is it possible to get direct link to the author or tag? I need something like `get_permalink` for posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`get_user_by`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_by) and [`get_term_by`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) functions:

```
// user
$user = get_user_by( 'login', 'someuser' );
if( $user ){
    echo get_author_posts_url( $user->ID );
}

// tag
$term = get_term_by( 'name', 'Sometag', 'post_tag' );
if( $term ){
    echo get_term_link( $term );
}
```